# How to download sketch with quote included

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I will try this one more time.

I am having trouble getting the quote to download as part of the sketch canvas. I am using sketch.js.

Here is the jsfiddle, you can draw like MSpaint but I when pressing the download button only what is drawn is copied. I would like the sketch and the words downloaded.

http://jsfiddle.net/e1ovm9mn/

I should also add that I am quite new to all.

Here is the code

```
<body>

    <nav>

        <div id="SketchTools">
    <!-- Basic tools -->
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#000000" title="Black"><img src="img/black_icon.png" alt="Black"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#ff0000" title="Red"><img src="img/red_icon.png" alt="Red"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#00ff00" title="Green"><img src="img/green_icon.png" alt="Green"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#0000ff" title="Blue"><img src="img/blue_icon.png" alt="Blue"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#ffff00" title="Yellow"><img src="img/yellow_icon.png" alt="Yellow"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#00ffff" title="Cyan"><img src="img/cyan_icon.png" alt="Cyan"/></a>

    <!-- Advanced colors -->
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#e74c3c" title="Alizarin"><img src="img/alizarin_icon.png" alt="Alizarin"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#c0392b" title="Pomegrante"><img src="img/pomegrante_icon.png" alt="Pomegrante"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#2ecc71" title="Emerald"><img src="img/emerald_icon.png" alt="Emerald"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#1abc9c" title="Torquoise"><img src="img/torquoise_icon.png" alt="Torquoise"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#3498db" title="Peter River"><img src="img/peterriver_icon.png" alt="Peter River"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#9b59b6" title="Amethyst"><img src="img/amethyst_icon.png" alt="Amethyst"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#f1c40f" title="Sun Flower"><img src="img/sunflower_icon.png" alt="Sun Flower"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#f39c12" title="Orange"><img src="img/orange_icon.png" alt="Orange"/></a>

    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#ecf0f1" title="Clouds"><img src="img/clouds_icon.png" alt="Clouds"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#bdc3c7" title="Silver"><img src="img/silver_icon.png" alt="Silver"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#7f8c8d" title="Asbestos"><img src="img/asbestos_icon.png" alt="Asbestos"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#34495e" title="Wet Asphalt"><img src="img/wetasphalt_icon.png" alt="Wet Asphalt"/></a>
   </br> <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#ffffff" title="Eraser"><img src="img/eraser_icon.png" alt="Eraser"/></a>

    <!-- Size options -->
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-size="1"><img src="img/pencil_icon.png" alt="Pencil"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-size="3"><img src="img/pen_icon.png" alt="Pen"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-size="5"><img src="img/stick_icon.png" alt="Stick"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-size="9"><img src="img/smallbrush_icon.png" alt="Small brush"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-size="15"><img src="img/mediumbrush_icon.png" alt="Medium brush"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-size="50"><img src="img/bigbrush_icon.png" alt="Big brush"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-size="90"><img src="img/bucket_icon.png" alt="Huge bucket"/></a>

    <a href="#SketchPad" data-download='png' id="DownloadPng">Download</a>
    <br/>
  </div>
        <div class="links">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="ficon.png" alt="Facebook"></li>
            <li><img src="igramicon.png" alt="Instagram"></li>
            <li><img src="picon.png" alt="Pinterest"></li>
            <li><img src="mcicon.png" alt="Mixcloud"></li>
            <li><img src="twicon.png" alt="Twitter"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="message">

        <div id="quote"></div>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var quotes = [
        { text: "Snuggletooth likes pancakes"},
        { text: "Would you like Snuggletooth to tuck you in?"},
        { text: " Snuggletooth loves you"},
        { text: "Snuggletooth is here for you"},
        { text: "Did you know that Snuggletooth </br>can be in 2 places at once?"},
        { text: "Heyyyy!<br> I was just thinking about you </br>Love Snuggletooth" },
        { text: "Wanna Sandwich??</br>xSnuggletooth"},
        { text: "Want some breakfast???</br> ;) Snuggletooth"},
        { text: "Snuggletooth-a-riffic!!!"},    
        { text: "Snuggletooth makes great popcorn!"},
        { text: "Come over to Snuggletooth's! He makes a great guacamole!"},
        { text: "Snuggletooth likes his bubblebaths to smell like bubblegum"},
        { text: "Snuggletooth wants to know what are you up to later?"},
        { text: "Snuggletooth-a-licious!!!"},
      ];
      var quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
      document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML =
        '<p>' + quote.text + '</p>' +
        '' +  '';
    })();
  </script>

    </div>
    </nav>
    <canvas id="SketchPad" width="1125" height="600">

    </canvas>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('#SketchPad').sketch();
    });
  </script>
 </body>
```

And here is the sketch.js

```
var __slice = Array.prototype.slice;
(function($) {
  var Sketch;
  $.fn.sketch = function() {
    var args, key, sketch;
    key = arguments[0], args = 2 <= arguments.length ? __slice.call(arguments, 1) : [];
    if (this.length > 1) {
      $.error('Sketch.js can only be called on one element at a time.');
    }
    sketch = this.data('sketch');
    if (typeof key === 'string' && sketch) {
      if (sketch[key]) {
        if (typeof sketch[key] === 'function') {
          return sketch[key].apply(sketch, args);
        } else if (args.length === 0) {
          return sketch[key];
        } else if (args.length === 1) {
          return sketch[key] = args[0];
        }
      } else {
        return $.error('Sketch.js did not recognize the given command.');
      }
    } else if (sketch) {
      return sketch;
    } else {
      this.data('sketch', new Sketch(this.get(0), key));
      return this;
    }
  };
  Sketch = (function() {
    function Sketch(el, opts) {
      this.el = el;
      this.canvas = $(el);
      this.context = el.getContext('2d');
      this.options = $.extend({
        toolLinks: true,
        defaultTool: 'marker',
        defaultColor: 'black',
        defaultSize: 5
      }, opts);
      this.painting = false;
      this.color = this.options.defaultColor;
      this.size = this.options.defaultSize;
      this.tool = this.options.defaultTool;
      this.actions = [];
      this.action = [];
      this.canvas.bind('click mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseleave mouseout touchstart touchmove touchend touchcancel', this.onEvent);
      if (this.options.toolLinks) {
        $('body').delegate("a[href=\"#" + (this.canvas.attr('id')) + "\"]", 'click', function(e) {
          var $canvas, $this, key, sketch, _i, _len, _ref;
          $this = $(this);
          $canvas = $($this.attr('href'));
          sketch = $canvas.data('sketch');
          _ref = ['color', 'size', 'tool'];
          for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
            key = _ref[_i];
            if ($this.attr("data-" + key)) {
              sketch.set(key, $(this).attr("data-" + key));
            }
          }
          if ($(this).attr('data-download')) {
            sketch.download($(this).attr('data-download'));
          }
          return false;
        });
      }
    }
    Sketch.prototype.download = function(format) {
      var mime;
      format || (format = "png");
      if (format === "jpg") {
        format = "jpeg";
      }
      mime = "image/" + format;
      return window.open(this.el.toDataURL(mime));
    };
    Sketch.prototype.set = function(key, value) {
      this[key] = value;
      return this.canvas.trigger("sketch.change" + key, value);
    };
    Sketch.prototype.startPainting = function() {
      this.painting = true;
      return this.action = {
        tool: this.tool,
        color: this.color,
        size: parseFloat(this.size),
        events: []
      };
    };
    Sketch.prototype.stopPainting = function() {
      if (this.action) {
        this.actions.push(this.action);
      }
      this.painting = false;
      this.action = null;
      return this.redraw();
    };
    Sketch.prototype.onEvent = function(e) {
      if (e.originalEvent && e.originalEvent.targetTouches) {
        e.pageX = e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageX;
        e.pageY = e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageY;
      }
      $.sketch.tools[$(this).data('sketch').tool].onEvent.call($(this).data('sketch'), e);
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    };
    Sketch.prototype.redraw = function() {
      var sketch;
      this.el.width = this.canvas.width();
      this.context = this.el.getContext('2d');
      sketch = this;
      $.each(this.actions, function() {
        if (this.tool) {
          return $.sketch.tools[this.tool].draw.call(sketch, this);
        }
      });
      if (this.painting && this.action) {
        return $.sketch.tools[this.action.tool].draw.call(sketch, this.action);
      }
    };
    return Sketch;
  })();
  $.sketch = {
    tools: {}
  };
  $.sketch.tools.marker = {
    onEvent: function(e) {
      switch (e.type) {
        case 'mousedown':
        case 'touchstart':
          this.startPainting();
          break;
        case 'mouseup':
        case 'mouseout':
        case 'mouseleave':
        case 'touchend':
        case 'touchcancel':
          this.stopPainting();
      }
      if (this.painting) {
        this.action.events.push({
          x: e.pageX - this.canvas.offset().left,
          y: e.pageY - this.canvas.offset().top,
          event: e.type
        });
        return this.redraw();
      }
    },
    draw: function(action) {
      var event, previous, _i, _len, _ref;
      this.context.lineJoin = "round";
      this.context.lineCap = "round";
      this.context.beginPath();
      this.context.moveTo(action.events[0].x, action.events[0].y);
      _ref = action.events;
      for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        event = _ref[_i];
        this.context.lineTo(event.x, event.y);
        previous = event;
      }
      this.context.strokeStyle = action.color;
      this.context.lineWidth = action.size;
      return this.context.stroke();
    }
  };
  return $.sketch.tools.eraser = {
    onEvent: function(e) {
      return $.sketch.tools.marker.onEvent.call(this, e);
    },
    draw: function(action) {
      var oldcomposite;
      oldcomposite = this.context.globalCompositeOperation;
      this.context.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";
      action.color = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
      $.sketch.tools.marker.draw.call(this, action);
      return this.context.globalCompositeOperation = oldcomposite;
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

And just in case here is the css

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Codystar);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster);



img {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;


}
li{

}
ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;


}
.message {
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-top: 20%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Lobster, Codystar, arial;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #ff0000;


}



.links {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 1em;
}


#SketchPad {
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    position: fixed;


}

#DownloadPng {

    padding: 4px 2px;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 100%;
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #fff;
    display:inline-block;
    /*vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;*/
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: background 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background 0.1s ease-in-out;
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #2ecc71;
    box-shadow: 0px 7px 0px 0px #27ae60;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#DownloadPng:hover {
    background-color: #27ae60;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

#DownloadPng:active {
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #27ae60;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

#SketchTools {
    width: 65%;
    height: 5%;
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: .2em;
}
```

Comment: This question seems to be the answer you are looking for ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25979845/html5-canvas-filltext-disappears-with-sketch-js

Comment: Definitely not a full answer here, but you could put the quote directly in the canvas instead of a div that is overlayed on the canvas.  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/shmm76ko/) is an updated jsFiddle.  It's not formatted, or even really loaded in the correct spot, but you can see using the `context.fillText()` method, you can get what you're looking for.

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 thanks but no thats not the answer I was looking for

Comment: @Tom Thanks!!! I think this is what I was seeking :) I just need to double-check and make sure that everything is ok

Comment: @Tom Thanks this works, but I am having trouble figuring out why it isn't styled with the CSS file